# Deleted podcasts in error

Tags: restore, podcasts

I've deleted ALL my unplayed Podcasts in error. I immediately went to the Recycle bin and restored them but I can't find them. Please could you assist?

Comment: Where were these podcasts *before* you deleted them? Where do you expect them to be. What software are / were you using to download and organize these podcasts? Without this information, no one can possibly help you.

Comment: Have you tried restoring them from your regular backups?

Answer (score 1):

If they were in your recycle bin and you were able to restore them, they should be back where they came from.

Otherwise, search your computer by names.

I suspect you have completely deleted them.